# How to separate multiple parts of a line using ';' using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a '.GS3' file with multiple lines like this one:

```
0123456789  aaa.aaa3456
```

I want to separate it like this:

```
01234;56789  ;aaa.aaa;3456
```

I know the start and end of each part of the line. Is it possible to do this considering multiple lines? For example:

```
0123456789  aaa.aaa3456
aaaaabbbbbbbxxxxxxxwwww
```

Into

```
01234;56789  ;aaa.aaa;3456
aaaaa;bbbbbbb;xxxxxxx;wwww
```

Comment: It's doable but fiddly with `sed` if the fields all have a fixed length. It is also doable with Awk, Perl, Python … with different degrees of difficulty, and they'll probably handle variable-length fields better.

Comment: please update the question with an explanation of how you determine where to place the semi-colons; will the results always have 4 fields (delimited by semi-colons)?  will all lines be of the same length?  also of interest ... what have you tried so far and what were the (wrong) results you generated?

Answer (score 1):

.. but if it does have fixed lengths you can do it this way:

```sh
$ sed -r 's/^(.{5})(.{7})(.{7})(.{4})$/\1;\2;\3;\4/' test.txt 
01234;56789  ;aaa.aaa;3456
aaaaa;bbbbbbb;xxxxxxx;wwww
```

I think `.{5}` is self explanatory. Due to the `-r` option the first group `(.{5})` can be referenced by `\1`. It's a group due to `(` and `)`.

The characters `^` and `$` represent the beginning and ending of every line in the file test.txt.

Comment: I have multiple files to do this and each one have around 350000 lines. This way I'd have to copy every line and put into the ".sh" file, right? I've tried this in python: (edit of the problem)

Comment: Note that `-r` is in GNU `sed`, as is `-E` which means the same (extended regular expressions).  However, `-E` is available with BSD `sed` (also used on macOS), but `-r` is not.  Some other platforms under the [tag:unix] tag might have neither option.  In that case, you have to prefix the bracketing characters (`(){}`) with backslashes — which is where 'fiddly' becomes an apt term for the process.

Comment: @GABRIELANDRADEQUEIROZ: You need to show more lines of data — input and required output.  If all your lines are similar to what's shown in the question, then the mapping here is OK.  (So, could `9876543210  zzz.zzz9987` be a valid input, requiring output `98765;43210  ;zzz.zzz;9987`?)  If other formats are valid inputs, how on earth are we to tell where the inputs should be split up if you don't tell us?

Comment: I agree with @JonathanLeffler

Comment: @GABRIELANDRADEQUEIROZ: If you're even thinking of putting all 350,000 lines into your script, there's something seriously wrong.

Comment: @GABRIELANDRADEQUEIROZ what Jonathan says. It's better to automate it with `find` or something more appropriate.